# Is "looks like" a group verb?

Tags: grammar

I was asked to fill in the blank with a group verb.

The child ____ his father. (To resemble)

Would "looks like" be a correct group verb? If not, why ?

Comment: Does it consist of a verb and one or more further elements which together function as a single verb? Does your dictionary tell you that "look like" means "resemble"?

Answer (score 1):

A **group verb** is either a *phrase verb* or a *prepositional verb*.

- [**look like**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/look-like-someone-something) is a phrasal verb which means *to be similar in appearance to someone or something* (*[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look%20like) - to have an appearance that is very similar to (someone or something) :  to resemble (someone or something) You look just like your mother! That powdered sugar looks like snow.*)

Another possible phrasal verb is "[to take after](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+after)" - *To resemble in appearance, temperament, or character.*

If they mean *resemble in appearance* then "**look like**" is more common but if they mean *resemble in character or intentions* then "**take after**" is more common.